# Can you use "“there’s more where that came from” to refer to people?

Tags: idioms

For example, there's an article that lists promising young scientists and one of them is from our team. Would it be appropriate to say, "there's more where that came from" to mean that we have more promising scientists in our team? Or is there a better way of saying it? Using that to refer to people sounds off to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard this idiom being used for people, It is commonly used for things.
Ex. You thank your friend for some cake, and he replies **there is more where** **that came from**. This means there is more of the same to follow if you want it.
If you refer to promising scientists you might say **there are many more like him/her.**

Comment: That's my concern. I want to say, we have more like him but with the same oomph as there's more where that came from. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: I cant think of other idioms with a similar meaning  which have the same oomph you need. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

My added comment didn't appear so how about this:

You could substitute the word **that** for **they**
Ex. There is more where **they** came from.
OR you could say **She is just one of many**.(meaning there are many more like her to come).
The use of **they** in the idiom above relates more to people compared to **that** which ,although it can refer to people, is generally used for things.
I hope that helps.